# Range of Microsoft Band accelerometer?

Tags: accelerometer, microsoft-band

I've written some code (based on Iris Classon's example) to stream accelerometer and gyrometer data from a Microsoft Band to a laptop. I'm using the `IBandClient` method `SensorManager.Accelerometer.StartReadingsAsync()` to subscribe to the Band's sensor streams.

Looking at my data, it seems that the accelerometer signal is being clipped at 8 g. Is this the absolute range limit of the sensor, or is there a way to increase the range?

[image: hand acceleration during punching]

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no way how to increase range of the sensor.
Band SDK does not support changing max Accelerometer data resolution (usually 2/4/8/16 G).
I doubt that this will change in the future.